# Checking If a path exists in a Binary Tree using DFS not working

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree, depth-first-search

I need to check if a path exists in a binary tree. I am given a list of elements and a binary tree to traverse through. I am using DFS to check if the path exists or not. The idea is that I should find if this path exists from root node to leaf node.

I know I can find if the path exists if I do something like the following...

```
class TreeNode:
  def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
    self.val = val
    self.left = left
    self.right = right

def find_path(root, sequence):
  if root is None:
    return len(sequence) == 0

  return find_path_helper(root, sequence, 0)

def find_path_helper(current_node, sequence, sequence_index):
  if current_node is None:
    return False

  sequence_length = len(sequence)

  if sequence_index >= sequence_length or current_node.val != sequence[sequence_index]:
    return False
  
  if current_node.left is None and current_node.right is None and sequence_index == sequence_length - 1:
    return True

  return find_path_helper(current_node.left, sequence, sequence_index + 1) or \
         find_path_helper(current_node.right, sequence, sequence_index + 1
```

However, my first thought without thinking about the efficiency of the code was to keep a list of the path from root to leaf and compare it with the list to be found but I cannot get it to work and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
class TreeNode:
  def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
    self.val = val
    self.left = left
    self.right = right

def find_path(root, sequence):
  if root is None:
    return len(sequence) == 0

  return find_path_helper(root, sequence, [])

def find_path_helper(current_node, sequence, current_sequence):
  if current_node is None:
    return False

  current_sequence.append(current_node.val)

  if current_node.left is None and current_node.right is None:
    return current_sequence == sequence

  return find_path_helper(current_node.left, sequence, current_sequence) or \
         find_path_helper(current_node.right, sequence, current_sequence)
```

but just returns false even when true. I was thinking that current_sequence will have the current path after traversing from root to leaf.

The tree is for example

```
         1
       /  \
      0   1
      |   |\
      1   6 5
```

and I need to check if the path 1 -> 1 -> 6 exists

The following is an example of the tree

```
root = TreeNode(1)
root.left = TreeNode(0)
root.right = TreeNode(1)
root.left.left = TreeNode(1)
root.right.left = TreeNode(6)
root.right.right = TreeNode(5)

sequence = [1, 1, 6]

print(find_path(root, sequence))
```

```
class TreeNode:
  def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
    self.val = val
    self.left = left
    self.right = right

def find_path(root, sequence):
  if root is None:
    return len(sequence) == 0

  return find_path_helper(root, sequence, [])

def find_path_helper(current_node, sequence, current_sequence):
  if current_node is None:
    return False

  current_sequence.append(current_node.val)

  if current_node.left is None and current_node.right is None:
    return current_sequence == sequence

# if I pass in a copy of current_sequence it works
  # I'm not sure why this does though
  return find_path_helper(current_node.left, sequence, list(current_sequence)) or \
         find_path_helper(current_node.right, sequence, list(current_sequence))
```

This last code works but I do not know why I have to pass in a copy of `current_sequence`

Comment: How are you representing the tree?

Comment: The posted code isn't valid Python.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the `def`. It's a binary tree. A parent node with no more than 2 child nodes

Comment: Still not valid Python, and you didn't answer *how* you are representing the tree.

Comment: Oops. I just noticed it. I was writing it over again when posting the question. I fixed the argument that was being passed into find_path_helper function

Comment: Please provide an example of calling `find_path`.

Comment: I went ahead and added it, but I also added some code that seems to work for me. But I don't understand why it's working.

Comment: And the definition of `TreeNode` is...?

Comment: I have other recursive calls I added below a comment in my code. I'll split the code up. I just thought it would be too much repeated code.

Comment: I split up the code the last code I posted works but I still do not understand why I need to pass in a copy of my list into my recursive call

Comment: "This last code works but I do not know why I have to pass in a copy of current_sequence"--you have to pass a copy otherwise all the children are using the same list.  For instance, In exploring the left path values are added to current_sequence.  If the left path result is False you explore the right path with all the values that were added when you previously explored the right path.  Makes sense?

Comment: Yes, I believe it does. Does this mean that I could just add `del current_sequence[-1]` after my recursive calls in order to remove the current elements from current_sequence while going up the recursive call stack instead of passing a new copy of current_sequence. I tried doing this as well but seems not to work and returns False only

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a mutable object like a list to a function, the local variable parameter it's assigned to isn't a copy of the data in the list. Both variables refer to the same underlying list object. Changes made to the list through one variable reflect on the list visible from the other variable.

You can see this behavior with a simple example:

```py
>>> def foo(L):
...     print(id(L))
...     L[0] = 42
... 
>>> X = [1, 2]
>>> id(X)
139874008311168
>>> foo(X)
139874008311168
>>> X
[42, 2]
```

In your recursive calls, all local `current_sequence` variables refer to the same list in memory.

When your recursive calls resolve and the call stack pops back to a parent call scope from a left subtree exploration that didn't find a valid path, the `current_sequence` list still retains incorrect values from that failed traversal. These values must be ignored when exploring the right subtree for the algorithm to work.

Making a copy of the list solves the problem by making each list a different object per frame, but it's inefficient. Better is to use `append()` and `pop()` to mutate the same list per call, or skip the secondary list entirely and pass an index/depth parameter to compare the `i`-th node to the `i`-th list index:

```py
def find_path(root, sequence, depth=0):
    if (
        root and 
        not root.left and 
        not root.right and
        depth == len(sequence) - 1 and 
        root.data == sequence[depth]
    ):
        return True
    elif (
        not root or 
        depth >= len(sequence) or 
        sequence[depth] != root.data
    ):
        return False

    return (find_path(root.left, sequence, depth + 1) or 
            find_path(root.right, sequence, depth + 1))

class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right


if __name__ == "__main__":
    r"""
        1
       / \
      2   3
     /   / \
    4   5   6
    """
    root = Node(
        1,
        Node(
            2,
            Node(4),
        ),
        Node(
            3,
            Node(5),
            Node(6),
        ),
    )
    should_be_true = [[1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 2, 4]]
    assert all(find_path(root, x) for x in should_be_true)

    should_be_false = [
        [1, 2, 5],
        [1, 3, 4],
        [1, 3],
        [1, 3, 3, 3],
        [1, 3, 5, 5],
        [],
        [1, 2],
    ]
    assert all(not find_path(root, x) for x in should_be_false)
```